# android NDK build command error

Tags: android, android-ndk

Here is the build command used by me and the error too

```
D:\AndroidWorkSpace\CApplication>D:\android-ndk-r8b-windows\android-ndk-r8b\ndk-
build.cmd
Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: ./jni/Android.mk
D:/android-ndk-r8b-windows/android-ndk-r8b/build/core/add-application.mk:133: **
* Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
```

Here is the make file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := CApplication
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ndk_demo.c
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Could some one let me know the issue

Comment: run ndk-build command  in root directory of your project  not in ndk folder

Answer (score 0):

`ndk-build` does not work with *make file*. The content you posted should be in file `Android.mk` under `jni` directory of your project.

As [@Sunny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/941864/sunny-kumar-aditya) pointed out, the *current directory* when you run `ndk-build` should be your project root, i.e. the parent directory of your `jni` directory.